# Looking for organisations promoting standard notation in mathematics

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, notation

Sometimes, I would like—in order to be as coherent and comprehensible as possible in the notation I use—to follow recommendations from some international working group, committee,  or organisation devoted to develop and promote standard mathematical language, similar to  IUPAC for chemistry or  IUPAP for physics.

Do you know if such thing exists for mathematics?

Answer (score 2):

The ISO has published a document ISO/DIS 80000-2 whose contents list can be viewed [here](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:64973:en). Unfortunately the full document is behind a paywall.

Comment: unfortunately that standard has a rather limited scope

Comment: @balage : True, the standards focus on what might be called *applicable mathematics*. Researchers in the more abstract realms of mathematics evolve their own standards, and probably don't need an external body to set standards for them.

Comment: @JohnBentin, “researchers … probably don't need an external body to set standards for them” that is the point of OP:  the rest of us need the secret decoder ring to understand the atypical notation.